# How to make a list of indexed words defined directly in text?

Tags: indexing

Is there any way to mark words in a text for the use of them in a list later on?

Example:

```
Hi my name is \addmark{Kris}, I need a \addmark{list} of words containing all the 
\addmark{marked words} by the end of the \addmark{document}.
\begin{itemize}
\item \addmark{fancy list}
\end{itemize}

\printmark
```

to look like this:

> Hi my name is Kris, I need a list of words containing all the marked words by the end of the document.
>
> - fancy list
>
> Kris, list, marked words, document and fancy list.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you mean something like an index? The `glossaries` package can do something like that for you.

Comment: But as far as I understood the `glossaries` package only allows predefined terms right? I would like to be able to define the terms for indexing in the text.

Comment: You can use `makeidx`.

Comment: `makeidx`seems good, but the `\makeindex` gives a list with index as title and I only need the indexed words in a paragraph as shown in my example - is there any workarround?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about something with `expl3` and sequences? `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_khaurum_wordlist_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{ \addmark }{ m }{
   \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_khaurum_wordlist_seq { #1 }
   #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \printmarks }{s}{
    \seq_gremove_duplicates:N \g_khaurum_wordlist_seq
    \seq_use:Nnnn \g_khaurum_wordlist_seq { ~ and ~ } { , ~ } { ~ and ~ }
    \IfBooleanT { #1 } {
        \seq_gclear:N \g_khaurum_wordlist_seq
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Hi my name is \addmark{Kris}, I need a \addmark{list} of words
containing all the \addmark{marked words} by the end of the
\addmark{document}.

\begin{itemize}
\item I'm a list of \addmark{items}
\item Ducks are \addmark{cool}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{1em}

\printmarks

\vspace{1em}

Another \addmark{value} here.

\vspace{1em}

\printmarks*

\vspace{1em}

The starred version cleared the \addmark{sequence}, so now
we can add  new \addmark{entries} again from start.

\vspace{1em}

\printmarks

\end{document}
```

[image: Quack]

When using `\printmarks*`, the sequence is printed and then cleared; so we can start a fresh sequence and add new entries afterwards.

Hope it helps. `:)`

<sub>Thanks to Marco Daniel and egreg for providing improvements to the code. `:)`</sub>

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: I just figured out that I can not add marks in a list - why is that?

Comment: @Khaurum: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand. Maybe you could update your question to reflect the problem. `:)`

Comment: I mean - when trying to `\addmark`in an `Itemize`-list the marked word does not appear in the `\printmarks`-list for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you should use a global sequence. So you can use inside a table too.

Comment: @Marco: ah. I replaced `\seq_put_right:Nn` by `\seq_gput_right:Nn`. Do you believe is that enough?

Comment: @Khaurum: I changed the code slightly, so now it might work. I'll just wait for the L3 wizards to check if it's correct. `:)`

Comment: I'll wait too as I am totally not understanding the code! I'm kind of new to LaTeX

Comment: @Khaurum: You can learn L3 interface without knowing any basics of TeX. This is one aim of the developer team.

Answer (score 7):

Since Paulo has already presented a LaTeX3 version, I'll stick to a classical approach. I only add a switch for printing red the marked words in the text, that may reveal useful during document writing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newif\ifshowmarked
\makeatletter
\newtoks\mark@toks
\mark@toks={\@gobble}
\newcommand{\mark@comma}{, }
\newcommand{\addmark}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{addmark@\detokenize{#1}}
   {% New marked word
    \global\@namedef{addmark@\detokenize{#1}}{#1}%
    \global\mark@toks=\expandafter{\the\mark@toks\mark@comma\@nameuse{addmark@\detokenize{#1}}}%
   }
   {
    % Already marked word, do nothing
   }%
   \ifshowmarked
     \textcolor{red}{#1}%
   \else
     #1%
   \fi
}

\newcommand{\printmarks}{%
  \the\mark@toks\relax
  \@ifstar{\global\mark@toks{\@gobble}}{}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

Hi my name is \addmark{Kris}, I need a \addmark{list} of words
containing all the \addmark{marked words} by the end of the
\addmark{document}.

\begin{itemize}
\item I'm a list of \addmark{items}
\item Ducks are \addmark{cool}
\end{itemize}

\vspace{1em}

\printmarks

\vspace{1em}

Another \addmark{value} here.

\vspace{1em}

\printmarks*

\vspace{1em}

\showmarkedtrue

The starred version cleared the \addmark{sequence}, so now
we can add  new \addmark{entries} again from start.

\vspace{1em}

\printmarks

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\addmark` is used to build a control sequence; if this command is already defined, we do nothing, otherwise define the control sequence and add it to a token register preceded by a comma and a space. The token register is initialized to contain `\@gobble`, so the first comma will not be printed. Finally, the word is printed (in red if the switch is on).

The `\printmarked` macro works in the same way: the token register's content is delivered; if the `*`-variant is used, the token register is reinitialized.

[image]

Note that the LaTeX3 is superior, because it allows for using the list of marked words in many different ways. It's doable also in the “classical” version, but reinventing the wheel many times. Also, no `\detokenize` trick is necessary with LaTeX3 to cope with special characters in the marked words, since the word is simply stored as is.

Just comparing the code clearly shows the superiority of the LaTeX3 approach.

---

Adding the switch to the LaTeX3 version is easy. Add

```
\bool_new:N \g_khaurum_highlight_bool
\NewDocumentCommand{\showmarkedtrue}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_khaurum_highlight_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showmarkedfalse}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_false:N \g_khaurum_highlight_bool
 }
```

and change the definition of `\addmark` to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{ \addmark }{ m }
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_khaurum_wordlist_seq { #1 }
  \bool_if:NTF \g_khaurum_highlight_bool { \textcolor}{red}{#1} } { #1 }
 }
```